# C#, WPF. Why TextBox would not show text in series?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have made simple window with a Button and someTextBox.

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        someTextBox.Clear();
        someTextBox.Text += "Some text\n";
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        someTextBox.Text += "Some text\n";
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        someTextBox.Text += "Some text\n";
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        someTextBox.Text += "Some text\n";
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
```

Why after 4 seconds appearing all four lines with "Some text\n"? Not just one line "Some text\n" every second? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Compilation might be optimizing the code

Comment: You need to implement MVVM to work with WPF

Comment: I simplified issue in this example. In real, I'm trying download 6 HTML pages from different web sites. Some sites are fast, some are slow. To make download faster I try to do it in parallel. Used different Tasks, Threads even BackGroundWorker. In all cases I got result for all pages at same tame - time which required download page from slowest web site. Is MVVM will fix the issue?

Comment: when you update the text the first time, it does not notify the UI to update, so basically UI stays the same. Once the event is completed, then it updates the UI, therefore you get 4 lines at once. Your initial question and your question in comment are totally 2 different things. Please ask separately.

Comment: @ew4ab - Please try to put an example mimicking the real scenario from your code which uses tasks or backgroundworker. Problem with current code you have added is clearly that UI thread remains busy and not able to update the text till the end.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't update because you are updating on UI's `Thread`.

To archive this you need to create an additional `Thread` and starts it when user click the button. Inside that `Thread` you update the string intervally.

Constructor of your class:

```
 public Your_Class_Name()
 {
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer MyTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    MyTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);
    MyTimer.Interval=1000;
 }

 void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    someTextBox.Text += "Some text\n";
 }

 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     someTextBox.Clear();
     MyTimer.Start();
 }
```

Comment: Suggest changing the answer so that `MyTimer.Interval` is initialised to 1000 to be consistent with the question

Comment: Do you think this code snippet fixes the issue reported??

Comment: Sorry, this code doesn't work in WPF at all:

Error CS1061 'Timer' does not contain a definition for 'Tick' and no extension method 'Tick' accepting a first argument of type 'Timer' could be found

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        someTextBox.Clear();
        new Thread(MyTread).Start();
        (sender as Button).Content = "Thread started";
    }

    private void MyTread()
    {
        someTextAdd("Some text\n");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        someTextAdd("Some text\n");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        someTextAdd("Some text\n");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        someTextAdd("Some text\n");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
    private void someTextAdd(string text)
    {
        someTextBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background,
        new Action(() =>
        {
            someTextBox.Text += text;
        }));
    }
```

Thanks for comments.

Comment: Based on this example I can fix all problems in my project. I was surprised that code which I tested in Console application would not work in WPF application. Now I know why.